# CEILING in SQL does not return correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

`CEILING` in T-SQL does not return correct values in SQL Server 2012. Please see below details.

```
select CEILING(0.3333333333333333)
```

Result: 1

But I want to do a calculation of based on count of columns. Internal calculation is given below.

```
select CEILING((17 - 2) / 45)
```

Result: 0

```
(17 - 2) / 45 = 0.33333
```

But

```
select CEILING((17 - 2) / 45)
```

returns zero

I want to get one as result. What should I do?

Comment: mention the database you are using

Comment: Use at least one floating point literal? i.e (17-2) / 45.0. The original expressions works correctly in 'mysql'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended with a integer division. So

> 15/45 = 0

Try CASTing atleast one of the operand into decimal ,

```
SELECT CEILING((17-2)/CAST(45 AS DECIMAL (4,2))
```

OR like,

```
SELECT CEILING(15,45.0)
```

Comment: Thank you  Very much Maheswaran Ravisankar .Now it works fine